# Mongo. Query documents with an array whose childs ALL have to match a query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a query by using the mongo aggregation framework.
What I want to achive is to select the orders **where ALL shipments have been delivered more than a month ago**.

currently I am able to select the orders where AT LEAST ONE shipment has been delivered more than a month ago.

Here's what I have:

```
db['shop.orders'].aggregate(
{
  $match: { 
    shipments: { $elemMatch: { status: "Delivered", deliveredAt: {"$lte":new Date("2018-07-28")}} }
     }
})
```

How do I have to alter my query to only select the orders where ALL shipments have been delivered more than a month ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to apply your condition for each `shipment` and then use [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/) inside [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to check if all those elements match:

```
db.shop_orders.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { shipments: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$shipments",
                        as: "shipment",
                        in: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$shipment.status", "Delivered" ] },
                                { $lte: [ "$$shipment.deliveredAt", new Date("2018-07-28") ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work. I only needed to add a check to be sure the array was not empty.

I added this statement to my match stage (in an AND):
{
            "shipments.0" : { $exists: true }
          }

Comment: @brechtvhb included that check in my answer

Comment: Your updated query does not seem to work :(. It returns nothing

Comment: @brechtvhb I believe it still works, you can verify here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/D_wcy4dxKjy