# Query to return results when all objects in an array of object matches

Tags: mongodb

My document structure looks like this:

```js
users : [
  {_id:1,
  'name': 'xxxxx',
  'children':[
    {age:13, weight: 80 lbs},
    {age: 12, weight: 65 lbs}
  ]
  }
  {_id:2,
  'name': 'yyyyy',
  'children':[
    {age:11, weight: 65 lbs},
    {age: 9, weight: 55 lbs}
  ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get the objects where all the elements in the children array are less than 12 years old. 
so the expected output would look something like:

```js
[
  {_id:2,
      'name': 'yyyyy',
      'children':[
        {age:11, weight: 65 lbs},
        {age: 9, weight: 55 lbs}
      ]
      }
]
```

I tried elem match but that only looks for any matches in the array. I'm looking for all matches. I tried this but it didn't work.

```js
{"children":{"$all":[{"$elemMatch":{"age":{"$lte":12}}}]}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065224/mongo-query-documents-with-an-array-whose-childs-all-have-to-match-a-query/52065325#52065325 ?

Comment: yes it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { 
              $eq: [ { $reduce: { input: "$children", 
                                  initialValue: true, 
                                  in: { $cond: [ { $gte: [ "$$this.age", 12 ] }, "$$value", false ] }
                     } },                   
                     true 
              ] 
          } 
      } 
  }
])
```

The aggregation uses the [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) array operator to check if all elements in the `children` array have the `age` greater than or equal to 12. The reduction operation returns a boolean `true`or `false` (true only if all array elements have a match). The `$match` stage filters the documents with the result `true`.